# Retrieving value from Ajax in Laravel 5.2

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I want to retrieve the value from ajax, use it as a value when saving in the database

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function() {
    par = $(this).find("span.widgets").html(); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '/partA-save',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    'test': latest,
    'widget': par,
    _token: CSRF_TOKEN
    },error:function(log) {
    console.log(log);
  }
  });
  console.log(par);
  return true;
});
```

In console, the par variable correctly log the value when a user click the li inside ul. Now I want to use it in the controller for an if else statement

```
 public function save(Request $request)
{
    $newdata = $request->input('test');

    $newWidget = $request->input('widget');
    if ($newWidget == 'COST') {
        $us = new Cost();
        $us->api = $newWidget;
        $us->save();
    } else {

        $us = new Map();
        $us->api = $newWidget;
        $us->save();
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::post('/partA-save','PartAController@save');
```

Even if the user choose the COST, the controller always use the code in the else block. Any idea what I am lacking here? Also, how to debug this in the controller so that I can see whats in side in the variable $newWidget. If I change this like

```
 date: { 'widget': 'COST'
```

saves to COST.

using var_dump or dd return null.How to correctly set the value in Ajax?

Comment: You could use console.log() to see what was being sent, or add in `dd($request->input('widget'));` too see what is being retrieved in your controller.

Comment: Can you use `console.log($(this).find("span.widgets").html());` to see if you are retrieving the value correctly in the first place?

Comment: yes it is retrieving. The problem is it returns null when retrieving from controller. I suspect there is something wrong with my ajax coz it returns null even if change data: {'widget': 'value'}

Comment: Can you post your full controller function?

Comment: @James I updated my question, now I got methodNotAllowed exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

Change Your URL Calling From Ajax

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function() {
    par = $(this).find("span.widgets").html(); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{url("/partA-save")}}',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    'test': latest,
    'widget': par,
    _token: CSRF_TOKEN
    },error:function(log) {
    console.log(log);
  }
  });
  console.log(par);
  return true;
});
```

In Controller Replace Input with get method of request.

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $newdata = $request->get('test');

    $newWidget = $request->get('widget');
    if ($newWidget == 'COST') {
        $us = new Cost();
        $us->api = $newWidget;
        $us->save();
    } else {

        $us = new Map();
        $us->api = $newWidget;
        $us->save();
    }
}
```